# Insert regex pattern into db table

Tags: sql, regex, database

I want to insert a regex pattern into a table as a value and then retrieve it with a query. For example:

```
# insert expression
INSERT INTO table VALUES("[rh]at").

# returns 1 row
SELECT * from table where name == "hat";
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `a == b` means `a is equal to b`. It doesn't mean `a matches the regular expression b`.  But your database probably has a regexp_matches() function that you can use. Read the manual, or google it, or at least tell us which database you're using.

Comment: That's out of the box thinking! Nothing immediately comes to mind how to reverse "the natural order of things". Another thing though, `r|h[at]` has some issues. 1) if you want to match *rat* or *hat* then you want to clarify that with parenthesis `(r|h)`. 2) `[at]` means match a single character *"a"* or *"t"*. Does not match *"at"*.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I fixed the expression to match rat or hat, I'm sorry if this is ***not*** what you intended OP.